# Download and execute Avira detection

Tags: c#

I am trying to download and execute a JPEG file but it seems that Avira detects that as a virus. Is there a way I can still download my JPEG file without Avira blocking my whole software? The code I use:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo("filename.jpg");
    Client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, file.FullName);
    MessageBox.Show("Downloaded!");

    Process.Start(file.FullName);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "execute" a JPEG file?  Activate the default verb (probably "preview" but could be "edit" or "print")?  Execute machine code embedded inside the image container?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could worry about avira because that's what you happen to have installed, but if you are going to worry about avira then you should worry about the 50+ anti virus programs that you don't have installed, and that will have issues that you don't even know about.  At the end of the day, you can't worry about that crap.  You can simply write your code as best as you can, and if you are really concerned, warn people that false positives may happen but you guarantee it isn't a virus, and people will either trust you or not.  If you can provide your source code to users, then you'll gain a lot more credibility.

My point is, if you didn't have avira installed, you wouldn't even know about this issue.  I write tons of random code that avira would probably have issues with, and I get emails from users all the time thanking me.  One of my lines of code is exactly the same as yours when I open up an exported image.